# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Element'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Good day 
I'm getting an error whenever i try to run the python script below. Its suppose to give a sum of values extracted from an XML file.
The Error message is:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Element'

I've tried all options but the error still comes back. where am i going wrong?

Source file:

```
<commentinfo>
<comments>
<comment>
<name>TDK</name>
<count>5000</count>
</comment>
<comment>
<name>Swats</name>
<count>420</count>
</comment>
<comment>
<name>Tandwa</name>
<count>2000</count>
</comment>
</comments>
</commentinfo>
```

Python Code:

```
import urllib
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
u = urllib.urlopen('file.xml')
data = u.read()
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
lst = tree.findall('comments/comment')
print 'Value', len(lst)
score=[]
for item in lst:
    number=int(item)
    score.append(number)
    total=int(sum(score))
print 'Sum', total
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    number=int(item)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Element'
```

Comment: What is `n`? It isn't defined in your code.

Comment: `lst` isn't defined either.

Comment: I'd bet the OP meant to use `number` instead of `n`, but who knows...

Comment: The program is a follows:

Comment: i have also tried to add an int but still the same error

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that error message with the code you posted in the above comment.

Comment: If you really want some help you'll really have to post a minimal but complete set of code - including some sample data - which gives the problem when you run it. You can edit the question to add this code. Include everything. - the imports, the initializaction of the data variable with the xml sample data - everything, so that I could paste your code into an empty .py file and execute it, Also tell me the exact line I will see the error when I run this code.

Comment: You mean `number` not `n` in your code, don't you?

Comment: Why is `score` a list? Set `total = 0` before the loop. Use `total += number` instead of `score.append(n)`. Get rid of the call to `sum(score)`

Comment: Please don't use comments to post long code or input/output. This information belongs in the question itself; use the [edit] link to add it there with proper formatting.

Comment: just edited the code. Thanks Lev

Comment: Thanks @mharapatsetse, for future reference (your edit is now a perfect example of an MVCE), but this is how to best format a question so others can help you in the future:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Tx Alexander. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem that each "item" is an XML element:

If I modify the code as follows, you can see the error:

```
...
score = []
for item in lst:
    print(item)
    number = int(item)
    score.append(number)
    total = int(sum(score))
...
```

When it is run, we get on the first run before an error is raised.

```
<Element 'comment' at 0x7f9da76584a8>
```

An XML element is not an "integer" or a string that can be converted to an integer. We need to grab the item's data, and then convert this to an integer. The "comment" element is still the parent of the "count" element, so we want the **text** of the "count" element.

Assuming we have our tree, we can grab all our count elements as follows:

```
lst = tree.findall('comments/comment/count')
```

We can then get the values by using the `int()` builtin from the element's text:

```
# this is a generator expression, it tells the code how to run but doesn't do it yet
scores = (int(i.text) for i in lst)
```

And then, we can evaluate the total:

```
total = sum(scores)
```

The total code (after loading opening the file as data and reading it) is as follows:

```
print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
lst = tree.findall('comments/comment/count')
print('Value', len(lst))

scores = (int(i.text) for i in lst)
total = sum(scores)
print('Sum', total)
```

The result we get is:

```
Retrieved 230 characters
Value 3
Sum 7420
```

Comment: Waal, after cracking my head for 2 days finally the solution is now working. I have tested all the solution suggested in these comments and all are working fine. Thanks Guys for the response. from the suggested solutions, i have realised my problem was in identifying the Element in question.

Comment: Well if either of us has helped you, and answered your question, please mark the question as answered. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably intended to get the value of the `<count>` child element from each `<comment>` and sum them together? If so, then the following slight modifications to the for loop should be sufficient:

```
score = []
for item in lst:
    number = int(item.find("count").text)
    score.append(number)
total = sum(score)
print 'Sum', total
```

Comment: Alternatively `score = [int(item.find("count").text) for item in lst]`